# Using BufferedReader in android Activity class

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader

I want to save values of string array from textFile by using BufferedReader in android
But i am getting error in the LogCat
please anyone help to figure out to solve the problem
Thanks in advance.. :)

> 01-02 20:15:53.220: E/AndroidRuntime(817): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tester1/com.example.tester1.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

*LAYOUT*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:paddingLeft="16dp"
   android:paddingRight="16dp" >

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/list1"
       android:layout_width="60dp"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/list2"
       android:layout_width="60dp"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

*ACTIVITY*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView list1;
    ListView list2;
    String [] listArray;
    BufferedReader AirportLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            AirportLocation = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("F:/Airport-Location3.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listArray = new String[1168];

        String line1;
        int c = 0;// location detector
        try {
            while((line1 = AirportLocation.readLine())!=null){
                StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(line1);
                String airport = s.nextToken();
                listArray[c] = airport;
                c++;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        list2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listArray);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listArray);
        list1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        list2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your file loated in `F:` drive ?

Comment: I think his file is located in his system's F drive and trying to read in Emulator... You can not do like that... Emulator is treated as seperate virtual System and can't access resources of System (can do using adb help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are accessing the file from your HDD (local drive `(F:)`) which is not possible. If you want to read this file better you put it in the assets folder of your project and then,

```
AirportLocation = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("Airport-Location3.txt")));

String line = AirportLocation.readLine();
```

**Suggestion:** Please follow the naming convention of java, it says `Class` names start with caps and their references start with `lowercase` and then follow `CamelNotations`.

Comment: Happy helping you...!!! Njoy coding. And please don't call me sir, I am too learning.

Answer (score 1):

In your Android Project,

1. Create **raw** folder inside the **res** folder
2. Place **Airport-Location3.txt** inside the **raw** folder
3. Rename **Airport-Location3.txt** to **Airport_Location3.txt** (Remove Dash)

and change

```
AirportLocation = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("F:/Airport-Location3.txt"));
```

to

```
InputStream inStream = getApplicationContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.Airport_Location3);
InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(inStream);
AirportLocation = new BufferedReader(is);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the Problem is

```
listArray = new String[1168];
```

You are talking the string array of a constant length, and you are assigning the values from the your respective file, Obviously the data may exceed or not.

And the remaining part of the `listArray` will be remained with `null` 's

And you are assigning the same `listArray` to `listView` ,`ArrayAdapter` with **null** values in it. I guess this may be the Problem

Solution is to take the `Arraylist` if you dont know the exact values...